# How do I set up these ActiveRecord relationships properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations, relational-database

I have a problem understanding how to set up the ActiveRecord relationships correctly for the following scenarios...

Now I have this tree of products:

```
Product 
-> ProductTypes 
   -> Subtypes 
     -> Subtypes 
       -> ... 
         -> Subtypes 
           -> ProductItem
```

where Product is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_types
  has_one :product_item, :foreign_key => "product_id"
end
```

ProductType and Subtype is:

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :parent_type, :class_name => "ProductType"
  has_many :subtypes, :class_name => "ProductType", :foreign_key => "parent_type_id"
  has_one :product_item
end
```

and ProductItem is:

```
class ProductItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_type
  belongs_to :product
end
```

But I also want the tree to allow `Product` to have `ProductItem` only (i.e. without subtypes), such as:

```
Product 
-> ProductItem
```

How can I go about setting these up to achieve these requirements?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what ProductType is. If it is a categorization, then it might make sense to have that association of has_many :product_types. If what you really want are actual different types of Products, then I would use STI to make your life a little simpler. Plus I would simplify product_item to just item, unless you have good reason to.

http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/

STI Way
Add a migration to your Products table to add a type column:

```
add_column :products, :type, :string
```

Then change your models to be like the following:

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item
end
```

type_1.rb

```
class Type1 < Product
end
```

type_2.rb

```
class Type2 < Product
end
```

etc.

For your subtypes I would do the same thing (taking type1 for example):

subtype_1.rb

```
class Subtype1 < Type1
end
```

So now all your different types and subtypes have an item associated to them. Your item now just has an association to product and you're done.

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

If this isn't what you want then I'll be happy to change my answer if you provide more clarity.

Comment: Did this answer help you along your way?